# Redux reducer can't update redux state/props

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm struggling to update props/state from redux with TextInput(ReactNative).
I can get actions and initial state from redux to SignIn component, however I can't update email props(Input value).
I searched for a solution but I can't find one that solves my problem.

`SignInScreen` component receive actions in props and I can access AuthReducer from the component so I guess Redux structure is fine. Only in AuthReducer.js, return {...state, email: action.payload} doesn't update props.

Following is my code.
I've posted the important parts, but I will add more if needed.

AuthReducer.js

```
// I can access this reducer
// INITIAL_STATE will be shown TextInput components

import {EMAIL_CHANGED } from '../actions/actionTypes';
import { AlertIOS } from 'react-native';

const INITIAL_STATE = { email: 'this is shown' }

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMAIL_CHANGED:

      // This alert function works with inputted payload(email)
      AlertIOS.alert('Input', action.payload);

      // This return doesn't update props.email in SignInScreen Component
      return { ...state, email: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

configureStore.js

```
import AuthReducer from './reducers/AuthReducer';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    auth: AuthReducer
});

const configureStore = () => {
    return createStore(rootReducer);
};

export default configureStore;
```

SignInScreen.js

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { emailChanged } from '../../store/actions';
import etc...

onEmailChange = (text) => {
  this.props.emailChanged(text);
};

render() {
  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>Email:</Text>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="email@mail.com"
          autoCorrect={false}
          value={this.props.email}
          onChangeText={email => this.onEmailChange(email)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    email: state.auth.email
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { emailChanged })(SignInScreen);
```

App.js

```
import etc...

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigator 
          style={styles.container} //Stephen Girder course said this was good practice
                                //to ensure fills screen with flex: 1 
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }

const store = configureStore();

export default App;
```

package.json

```
"expo": "^32.0.0",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-navigation": "^3.10.2",
"react-redux": "^6.0.1",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
```

[image]

Comment: What does your action `emailChanged` look like?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to dispatch the action.
Try using the following in **SignInScreen.js**:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    email: state.auth.email
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
      emailChanged: value => dispatch(emailChanged(value))
  }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignInScreen);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, unfortunately it wouldn't work for my app